# Center order items text vertically on WooCommerce My account order view

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

The following code displays the product image in order items:

```php
// Display the product thumbnail in order view pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_image_in_order_item', 20, 3 );
function display_product_image_in_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        $product   = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 100, 100)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product object)
        if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 )
            $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail" style="float:left;display:block;width:150px; margin-right:10px;" >' . $thumbnail . '</div>' . $item_name;
                    
   }
    
    return $item_name;
}
```

However, I am trying to center the text of the product name and quantity, without success. The image is displayed on the left, and the text is on the right at the top... I would like to center it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should better provide the HTML output for the entire related table line where you want to center the text vertically, than the PHP code that displays the product image. For aligning text, see this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_align.asp

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the reply, I already know this tutorial.
unfortunately it didn't help more than that...
the text-align etc does not work and the text being in an href I do not see how to modify it in css...
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below the code

```
// Display the product thumbnail in order view pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_image_in_order_item', 20, 3 );
function display_product_image_in_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    // echo $item_name;
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        $product   = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 100, 100)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product object)
        if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 )
            $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail" style="width:150px; margin-right:10px;" >' . $thumbnail . '</div>' . $item_name.'';
                    
   }
    
    return $item_name;
}
```

And add below the CSS in your style.css

```
.woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item a, .woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item strong{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
}

.woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item .item-thumbnail{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks you Vel :) it's work perfectly.
Will not have arrived, I do not know well enough.
Only small problem I can no longer move the quantity x1 which is now stuck to the text.

Thank you in advance if you can help me further :)